# Using HTTP status codes with custom messages outside of controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to return HTTP codes that would contain a custom message outside of a controller.

For example, in a controller I can have

```
return BadRequest("Invalid");
```

Inside a regular method I tried the following code

```
return Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest("Invalid");
```

But I get the following message

"Non-invocable 'StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest' cannot be used like a method"

Is there anyway I can return HTTP codes with custom messages outside of a controller?

Comment: As the exception message says, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest` is a const int, not a function. You can't thus *invoke* it with `(` and `)`.

Comment: Correct. but is there anyway I can return HTTP codes with custom messages outside of a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BadRequest("Invalid")` returns an `BadRequestObjectResult` instance.

In similar way, you can return an instance of this class from your code via

```
return new BadRequestObjectResult("Invalid");
```